# Postgresql, change value of json inside function

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PotsgreSQL I have trigger function that was created like this:

```
new_json := row_to_json(NEW);
```

It contains json like this:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "country": {
     "code": "US"
  }
}
```

I want it to modify into this:

```
{
  "id": "US123",
  "country": {
    "code": "US"
  }
}
```

I want to append  country code into id and turn it into string.

I'm trying to do it this way:

```
new_json := new_json || json_build_object('id', new_json -> 'country' ->> 'code' || new_json ->> 'id')::jsonb;
```

However it throws to me an error:

Operator does not exist text ->> unknown
..id', new_json -> 'country' ->> 'code' || new_json ->> 'id'):

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without explicit parenthesis the argument is parsed as:

```
(((new_json -> 'country') ->> 'code') || new_json) ->> 'id'
```

If you put the parenthesis at the correct places it should work as expected

```
new_json := new_json || jsonb_build_object('id', (new_json -> 'country' ->> 'code') || (new_json ->> 'id'));
```

Comment: Alternatively - using the recommended JSONB - `new_json #>> '{country,code'}`